# Jekyll JSON incorrect character encoding

Tags: json, character-encoding, jekyll

I'm using [simple-jekyll-search](https://github.com/christian-fei/Simple-Jekyll-Search) to create a search page for my posts in Jekyll.

The JSON file to search is generated by:

```
[
{% for post in site.posts %}
{
"title"    : "{{ post.title | escape }}",
"category" : "{{ post.category }}",
"tags"     : "{{ post.tags | join: ', ' }}",
"url"      : "{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}",
"date"     : "{{ post.date | date: '%Y %B %-d' }}",
"content"  : "{{ post.content | strip_html | strip_newlines }}"
} {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
]
```

The problem is that certain characters are incorrectly encoded in the JSON file (though they appear correctly in the HTML). "You’ll" appears as "Youâ€™ll" in the JSON, for example. There's clearly an issue with incompatibility of character encoding, but I'm not sure where to fix it. Since it's only incorrect in the JSON, I'm guessing it's somewhere in this template to generate the JSON, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Comment: What's the encoding you are viewing the file? Are you sure it is saved wrong?

Comment: In the `search.json`? How can I check?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're viewing it in a text editor, which has to detect the file encoding. Assuming jekyll did nothing wrong, the text editor may have failed to choose an appropriate encoding.

Comment: I was viewing it in the browser (with the JSONView extension in Chrome). When I use the JSON file for the search functionality of simple-json-search, it's not correctly detecting it, either. (e.g., If I search for "you'll" it won't find the post.) Is this possibly an issue with the js search function also not using the proper encoding?

Comment: Is the text in question part of the "title" or "content"? Some of the string filters in Liquid call Ruby string functions that only work with ASCII text.

Comment: I've tried both, and the problem is there for both.

Comment: I pulled down your code and put both a ’ and a ⸗ character in a title and was not able to reproduce the issue.